# How to set python version on windows platform for matlab?

Tags: python, matlab

From MathWork documentation I've found this: [Set Python Version](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/system-and-configuration-requirements.html)
However I am not sure what to type in the command line on Matlab. I have python version 2.7

Should the command be

```
pyversion 2.7
```

How do I test it ? to check if it worked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**according to [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/system-and-configuration-requirements.html) in your answer**

To set the version, type:

```
pyversion executable
```

where executable is the full path to the Python executable file.

**to check version [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pyversion.html)** 
**Display Python Version for Your System**

```
pyversion
       version: '2.7'
    executable: 'C:\Python27\python.exe'
       library: 'C:\windows\system32\python27.dll'
          home: 'C:\Python27'
      isloaded: 0
```

Comment: Thank you. shokran.

Comment: yeah to ensure that change it to any other version and try should work fine